# Does the Iphone 1/2 have a compass inside?

Tags: iphone, gps, n95

Can one be simulated by periodicly syncing with GPS and in the meen while working with the accelerometer? I know for example that the N95 accelerometer is invarient to rotation on the Y axis (while beeing face up/down).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original iPhone and the iPhone 3G use GPS to calculate the heading, however the iPhone 3GS now has a 3-dimensional magnetometer compass in it.

This can only be done taking two GPS coordinates (while moving) and determining the direction from point A to B.

Comment: The heading from GPS only indicates what direction the phone is moving and only works if it is moving.  It doesn't tell you what direction it is facing like a compass does.  But it may be better than nothing if it meets your needs.

Comment: Yeah I know. Should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 2):

iPhone doesn't have a built in compass; but there is one created in software. It's called *[Compass Free](http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=284735786&mt=8)*, and unsurprisingly perhaps, it's free.

Comment: That was true: iPhone 1 and iPhone 3G have no compass, but later iPhones (3GS, 4, 4S) all have a compass.  iPads with 3G also have a compass (magnetometers).

Answer (score 0):

Extra info: The IPHONE 1 did not have GPS or compass.